# Which collection should I use to easely get certain object from it by the pair of properties?

Tags: java, collections, tableview, javafx-8

Info about network interfaces comes from several servers and must be shown in the table. Each interface must have `name` and `serverName`, they're not unique, but pair of them is.

**Problem:** Information comes every second, and I need to update fields of each interface with new data. So I need to get certain (identified by name and serverName) interface from some list with minimum effort (resources). Table works only with `observableList`, but searching through it is the overkill. It can contain thousand of interface objects.

Should I create own realization of list, which can be flatten to `observableList`, or the best way will be to hold `HashMap<String, NetInterface>` of each server (key is interface's `name`) with refences from `observableList`?

Comment: did you try something like http://stackoverflow.com/q/21713096/203657?

Answer (score 0):

HashMap>

use as auto increment for Integer.

Answer (score 0):

The best way will be using the unique thing(name+server name) as the key of your Hash Map.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `Map<String, Map<String, NetInterface>`, where the outer key is the name and the inner key is the server name.

Comment: And how should I pass this `Map` to TableView as model?

Comment: @Neka what do you mean? Maybe [edit the question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/34195344/edit) and add some code to show what you would like to do and how.

Comment: This is "meta" question, I realy don't know, how code example should looks like. Mapping model to TableView is going throug `TableView.setItems(ObservableList)` call, but 'Map' is `Map`, not `ObservrableList`