# How can i put a table inside the cell of another tableview in javafx?

Tags: java, javafx

I want to put a table inside another table in javafx.Till now i could able to put the table.Here my model is hashmap so basically i am mapping my cell to some key and add the hashmap to the table.But  on scrolling the  update items is called and however all the mapping is created again.Below has my code snipnet please tell me what am doing wrong here..

```
    @Override
    protected void updateItem(final HashMap<String, String> item, boolean empty) {
      super.updateItem(item, empty);

      if (item != null) {
        if (item instanceof HashMap) {
          Set<String> key = item.keySet();
          for (Iterator<String> it = key.iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
            String s = it.next();
            arraylist.add(s);

          }

          final TableView<Map<String, String>> table = new TableView<>();
          table.setPrefHeight(43);
          table.setEditable(true);
          TableColumn datacol[] = new TableColumn[item.size()];

          Callback<TableColumn, TableCell> cellFactory = new Callback<TableColumn, TableCell>() {
            public TableCell call(TableColumn p) {
              EditingCell editingCell = new EditingCell();
              editingCell.setTooltipMessage("Editing  " + p.getText());
              return editingCell;
            }
          };
          for (int i = 0; i < item.size(); i++) {

            datacol[i] = new TableColumn<>(arraylist.get(i));
            datacol[i].setCellValueFactory(new MapValueFactory(arraylist.get(i)));
            datacol[i].setMinWidth(30);
            datacol[i].setCellFactory(cellFactory);
          }

          table.getColumns().addAll(datacol);
          table.setItems(generateDataInMap(((HashMap<String, String>) (item))));

          table.widthProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Number>() {
            @Override
            public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Number> ov, Number t, Number t1) {
              // Get the table header
              Pane header = (Pane) table.lookup("TableHeaderRow");
              if (header != null && header.isVisible()) {
                header.setMaxHeight(0);
                header.setMinHeight(0);
                header.setPrefHeight(0);
                header.setVisible(false);
                header.setManaged(false);
              }
            }
          });
          setGraphic(table);

        }
      }
    }

    private ObservableList<Map<String, String>> generateDataInMap(HashMap<String, String> item) {
      ObservableList<Map<String, String>> allData = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

      allData.add(item);
      return allData;
    }
  }

  @Override
  public TableCell call(TableColumn p) {
    return new InnerTableCell();
  }
```

Comment: You have a map for each row like the Oracle example.  I did something that uses one map for the whole table.   http://stackoverflow.com/a/21339428/2855515

Comment: @brian yes that is  correct i am putting map for table column but i have a table where inside that table i have implemented a cell factory for another table .baiscall one cell of main table is overideen to fit for a inner table view

Comment: updateItem is where the cell gets drawn.  So it will run whenever you need a cell.  What is the original data you want in the whole table?

Comment: I have a hashmap   basically eachtime column name are changing so i   want to create the inner table again and gain so that i can newly  map the data to the table

Comment: You should just change the column name if that's what you want.  I don't know why you want a table in a table.  You should write it so there's just one table.

Comment: @brian Is it not recommended to use a table view  inside another

Comment: I don't think it was planned on.  Javafx has a nested column function that would take care of any display issues.  I just don't get what your data is shaped like.  You should show the declaration and a sample of your data.

Comment: There shouldn't be any problems with embedding tableviews inside of tableviews. Javafx is built on a scenegraph which should take care of all that.
If you don't want your tables to get recreated every time, you should save the tables in in a cache. At updateitem you should check if the cache contains the table you want, if not you create it on the spot.

Comment: This is very old question i have already achieved that