# How the performance of a JavaFx-MySQL application can be enhanced

Tags: mysql, performance, javafx, load-time

In my JavaFx application, i'm loading an ObservableList when a button is clicked and then display the list in a table.

the controller code:

```
 @FXML
   private void initialize() throws SQLException, ParseException, ClassNotFoundException {

    searchChoice.setItems(criteriaList);
    searchChoice.getSelectionModel().selectFirst();
    productIdColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().productIdProperty());
    unitColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().unitProperty());
    productTitleColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().titleProperty());
    productTypeColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().typeProperty());
    productUnitPriceColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> Bindings.format("%.2f", cellData.getValue().unitPriceProperty().asObject()));
    productQuantityColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().quantityProperty().asObject());
    productStatusColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().productStatusProperty());
    descriptionColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().descriptionProperty());
    reorderPointColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().reOrderPointProperty().asObject());
    surplusPointColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().surplusPointProperty().asObject());
    productIdColumn.setSortType(TableColumn.SortType.DESCENDING);
    productTable.getSortOrder().add(productIdColumn);

    productTable.setRowFactory(tv -> new TableRow<Product>() {
        @Override
        public void updateItem(Product item, boolean empty) {
            super.updateItem(item, empty);
            if (item == null) {
                setStyle("");
            } else if (item.getQuantity() < item.getReOrderPoint()) {
                setStyle("-fx-background-color: tomato;");
            }  else if (item.getQuantity() > item.getSurplusPoint()) {
                setStyle("-fx-background-color: darkorange;");
            } else {
                setStyle("-fx-background-color: skyblue;");
            }
        }
    });

    try {
        ObservableList<Product> productData = ProductDAO.searchProducts();
        populateProducts(productData);
        String[] expireDate = new String[productData.size()];
        String[] id = new String[productData.size()];
        String[] existingStatus = new String[productData.size()];
        for (int i = 0; i < productData.size(); i++) {
            expireDate[i] = productData.get(i).getExpireDate();
            id[i] = productData.get(i).getProductId();
            existingStatus[i] = productData.get(i).getProductStatus();
            DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat(app.values.getProperty("DATE_FORMAT_PATTERN"), Locale.ENGLISH);
            Date expireDateString = format.parse(expireDate[i]);
            Date in = new Date();
            LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.ofInstant(in.toInstant(), ZoneId.systemDefault());
            Date today = Date.from(ldt.atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant());
            if (expireDateString.before(today) && !existingStatus[i].equals(app.values.getProperty("STATUS_TYPE2"))) {
                ProductDAO.updateProductStatus(id[i], app.values.getProperty("STATUS_TYPE3"));
            }
            if (expireDateString.after(today) && !existingStatus[i].equals(app.values.getProperty("STATUS_TYPE2"))) {
                ProductDAO.updateProductStatus(id[i], app.values.getProperty("STATUS_TYPE1"));
            }
        }
        ObservableList<Product> productDataRefreshed = ProductDAO.searchProducts();
        populateProducts(productDataRefreshed);

        ObservableList<Product> productCodesData = ProductDAO.getProductCodes();
        ObservableList<Product> productTitlesData = ProductDAO.getProductTitles();
        ObservableList<Product> productTypesData = ProductDAO.getProductTypes();
        ObservableList<Product> productStatusData = ProductDAO.getProductStatus();
        String possibleProducts1[] = new String[productCodesData.size()];
        for (int k = 0; k < productCodesData.size(); k++) {
            possibleProducts1[k] = productCodesData.get(k).getProductId();
        }
        String possibleProducts2[] = new String[productTitlesData.size()];
        for (int k = 0; k < productTitlesData.size(); k++) {
            possibleProducts2[k] = productTitlesData.get(k).getTitle();
        }
        String possibleProducts3[] = new String[productTypesData.size()];
        for (int k = 0; k < productTypesData.size(); k++) {
            possibleProducts3[k] = productTypesData.get(k).getType();
        }

        String possibleProducts4[] = new String[productStatusData.size()];
        for (int k = 0; k < productStatusData.size(); k++) {
            possibleProducts4[k] = productStatusData.get(k).getProductStatus();
        }

        TextFields.bindAutoCompletion(searchField, possibleProducts1);
        TextFields.bindAutoCompletion(searchField, possibleProducts2);
        TextFields.bindAutoCompletion(searchField, possibleProducts3);
        TextFields.bindAutoCompletion(searchField, possibleProducts4);

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.ERROR);
        alert.setTitle(app.values.getProperty("ERROR_TITLE"));
        alert.setHeaderText(app.values.getProperty("FAILURE_MESSAGE"));
        alert.setHeaderText(app.values.getProperty("ERROR_GETTING_INFORMATION_FROM_DATABASE_MESSAGE"));
        alert.showAndWait();
        throw e;
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

the service mysql query :

```
  public static ObservableList<Product> searchProducts() throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {
    String selectStmt = "SELECT * FROM product";
    ResultSet rsPrdcts = DbUtil.dbExecuteQuery(selectStmt);
    ObservableList<Product> productList = getProductList(rsPrdcts);
    return productList;
}
```

The issue here is, when there are more than 200-300 items in the list the scene gets really slow to load. What countermeasures can I take regarding this matter? Any idea will be very much appreciated. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: This question would be better suited to https://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: Use an `ObservableMap` instead of an `ObservableList` if performance is important.

Comment: I've found a very good implementation example. You might benefit from this post.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16941980/populate-tableview-with-observablemap-javafx

Comment: You could move loading the data from the DB to a different thread. Otherwise there's probably not much you can do (assuming the connection to the db is the bottleneck here).

Comment: I have loaded way more than 200-300 items with zero problems. I am going to guess that your `for-loop` -> `for (int i = 0; i < productData.size(); i++) ` is the problem. That includes all the other `for-loops` that follow.

Comment: I suggest you retrieve data when you need it. That could possibly eliminate all the `for-loops` on startup. The other option is to create a splash screen that loads all the data before the application starts.

Comment: Show us the generated SQL statement, maybe we can help from that side.

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement an `ObservableList` which only retrieves the data which is rqeusted by the `TableView`. Currently you retrive all elements in the table and cast the retrieved list to an `ObservableList`.
The `TableView` uses the `.get(int idx)` method of the OL to retrieve all items which should be displayed and the `.size()` method for determining the size of the scrollbar. When you scroll the `TableView` will discard all items which are not displayed and call the get method again.

To solve your problem need to create a class which `implements ObservableList<E>`. First you need to implement the `.get(int idx)` and the `.size()` method, for all other methods I would `throw new UnsupportedOperationException()` and later on see which other method is needed. So the `.size()` method needs to execute the following query

```
SELECT count(*) FROM product
```

and the `get(int idx)` something like this

```
int numItems = 30;
int offset = idx - (idx % numItems)
SELECT * FROM product LIMIT offset, numItems
```

you can create an internal list which only holds e.g. 30 items from your db and whenever the requested `idx < offset || idx > offset + numItems` you issue a new db request.

I used this this approach with database tables with millions of rows and had a very performant GUI. You can also add paging to the `TableView` because with to many rows the scrollbar gets useless, but this is a different discussion.

**edit:**

I forgot to mention that this is called [Lazy Loading](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_loading)